# examples of " a variable that can be easily mistaken for a constant variable but is in fact a non-constant variable "

Tags: c++, constants

I'm new to C++ and is trying to learn the concept of constant expression. I saw the quote below from C++ primer 5th Edition.

> In a large system, it can be difficult to determine (for certain) that an initializer is a constant expression. We might define a const variable with an initializer that we think is a constant expression. However, when we use that variable in a context that requires a constant expression we may discover that the initializer was not a constant expression.

Could someone please give examples of a variable that can be easily mistaken for a constant variable but is in fact a non-constant variable? I want to be aware of the pitfulls of constant and non-constant variables and try to avoid them to the best of my ability.

Comment: `int n; cin >> n; int array[n];` seems to get a lot of newcomers. `n` is being read from the console, and thus cannot be part of a constant expression, but in a large system it may not be immediately obvious where `n` came from.

Comment: @AndyG Thanks for helping out! really appreciate it!

Comment: Preprocessor macros are another example: you might intuitively think they're constant, but they might end up calling some runtime function to get the value to return.  But, you'll find out when you try to compile.  A danger is that some systems do use a constant and others not - so your code might break when ported.  Another danger is that the order of initialisation of static / namespace-scope variables in different objects is unspecified, so if they depend on each other naively all hell can break loose.

Comment: In the paragraph above that statement as well, it says "... `const int sz = get_size();` ... On the other hand, even though `sz` is a `const`, the value of its initializer is not known until run time. Hence, `sz` is not a constant expression."

Comment: The text you quoted is about *constant expression* . However your question asks about *constant variable*. Those are completely different concepts, you seem mixed up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_initialization) provides a good example for that problem:

```
// code by http://en.cppreference.com/w/User:Cubbi, CC-by-sa 3.0
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

struct S {
    static const int c;
};
const int d = 10 * S::c; // not a constant expression: S::c has no preceding
                         // initializer, this initialization happens after const
const int S::c = 5;      // constant initialization, guaranteed to happen first
int main()
{
    std::cout << "d = " << d << '\n';
    std::array<int, S::c> a1; // OK: S::c is a constant expression
//  std::array<int, d> a2;    // error: d is not a constant expression
}
```